# Returning a list of categories nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am trying to return 2 lists using nopCommerce, Both lists are read-only,
I am looking for the simplest way in doing this as I am writing a metro app and I don't really want to spend weeks learning MVC . 
The first list is a list of categories from the base nopCommerce platform , the second list is a list of products.
Both lists need to be returned as JSON, to the calling client.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way I can get this list without calling custom code ?
2. I wrote a plugin using the following code

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Web.Mvc;
   using Nop.Core;
   using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;
   using Nop.Services.Catalog;
   using Nop.Services.Customers;
   using Nop.Core.Plugins;

   namespace Nop.Plugin.Other.ONWWW.Controllers
   {
       public class ONWWWController : Controller
       {
           public  ICategoryService _categoryService;

           public ONWWWController(ICategoryService categoryService)
           {
               this._categoryService = categoryService;
           }

           public ActionResult Index()
           {
               return Json(_categoryService.GetAllCategories(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           }

       }

   }
   ```

   Why, when i run the code, I get the following error ?

   > No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Your best bet is the *Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebServices* plugin in the original source code.

Question 2: Did you see that the only constructor you have is

```
public ONWWWController(ICategoryService categoryService)
```

Which must accept a parameter? In other words, you have not registered the dependency properly. Try looking at one of the *DependencyRegistrar.cs* file in any of the default plugin. The *Nop.Plugin.Misc.MailChimp* plugin, for example, has a *DependencyRegistrar.cs* that you can refer.

:)